# Total row with condition "group By"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have problem in query. I use posgresql. I need to get total row but with condition    "group by"

```
table qwe 
----------------------------
TIPE   | VAL
----------------------------
1      | 2
2      | 3 
2      | 1
2      | 4
3      | 1
3      | 3
```

the result I need is

```
-------------------------
TIPE   | VAL | TOTAL TIPE
-------------------------
1      | 2   | 3
2      | 8   | 3
3      | 4   | 3
```

the query I've tried so far

```
select tipe, sum(val), count(tipe) "total tipe" 
from qwe group by tipe order by tipe


-------------------------
TIPE   | VAL | TOTAL TIPE
-------------------------
1      | 2   | 1
2      | 8   | 3
3      | 4   | 2
```

Comment: how can you get the TOTAL TIPE output like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
select
    tipe, sum(val), count(tipe) over() as "total tipe"
from qwe
group by tipe
order by tipe
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/58f45/4)</kbd>**

You see, instead of counting number of not-null `tipe` records inside each group, you can count number of not null tipe over the whole resultset - that's why you need `over()` clause. It's called [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html).

Comment: please explain  over clause ...thnks

Comment: yes.. it works! but I still don't get it how to use over().
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

That's a strange request, however, I would suggest that you build a view that returns just the count(tipe) of the table and then join that view in? I haven't tested that but I am pretty sure that it would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    tipe, sum(val), max(cnt) "total tipe"
from qwe
join (select count(distinct(tipe)) "cnt" from qwe) v on true
group by tipe
order by tipe
```

[SQL-Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bd2b3/9/0)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is giving correct output .
For desired output , i don't know why it seems you require `TOTAL TIPE` value fixed as 3 .

```
select tipe, sum(val), 3 as "total tipe" 
from qwe group by tipe order by tipe
```

Comment: its not a fixed value. Its the total of the row

Comment: I think you just hard-coded "total tipe" by 3 instead of calculate the row count